# Number Pattern Programs in C#

Tags: c#, console

I want to print something like this

```
54321
5432
543
54
5
4
3
2
1
```

---

```
int n = 5;
Console.WriteLine();
for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    Console.Write(i.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve this with while-loops

```
int i = 5, input = 0;
while (i > 0)
{
    input *= 10;
    input += i--;
}

while (input > 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    input /= 10;
}

while (input > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input--);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1L6j6A

Comment: little bit change in output I want after 54  next line should be 5 and then 4,3,2,1 Please help me if possible